# When did green LEDs become as cheap as red LEDs?

Tags: history, hardware, cost

Blue LEDs in the cheap, practical form we know them today, arrived in the 90s; before that, the choices were red and green.

I want to say there was a time some years before that when green LEDs became cheap and practical, before which red was the color of choice, but I'm not quite sure why I have that feeling; it's true green has more energy per photon than red, but that fact alone does not say anything about dates. I do remember the Vic-20 having a red power indicator, but that could have been just an aesthetic choice for all I know.

When did green LEDs get to the point where the only advantages of red were aesthetic and ergonomic, not cost or efficiency?

Comment: LEDs have existed since the 1940s, possibly earlier.  Although rare and expensive then, they predate their use in computers by decades.  This may be better asked on Electronics.SE but check their requirements.

Comment: I agree with @Chenmunka; there already are similar questions on [Electronics.SE] about blue and white LEDs.

Comment: @Chenmunka While this would be on-topic for both forums per charter, my experience of Electronics.SE is that any question with the slightest whiff of historical content, even when clearly on-topic for the forum, is quickly referred to here. And I have certainly seen pictures of very old equipment with LEDs, but in each case where I was able to check the color, they were red. How far back do green LEDs go?

Comment: I first encountered LEDs in 1950s transistor radios.  They were white or yellow.  My father told me that he used them in military radios during WWII.  I've seen green LEDs in the 1970s and I built kit with infra-red LEDs in the late 1970s.

Comment: @Chenmunka are you sure there is no confusion with EL devices?

Comment: @rackandboneman:  The infra-red ones I mentioned were ELEDs yes.  I'm not confusing with Electroluminescent Devices if that's what you mean.

Comment: Electroluminescent devices, I mean. Completely different technology compared to LEDs.

Comment: Your question might fit  *retro*, but definitively not  *computing*

Comment: _" my experience of Electronics.SE is that any question with the slightest whiff of historical content, [...] is quickly referred to here. "_ Sure? Mayve if its about retro **computing**, but LEDs are nothign specific to computing. They are not more related than resistors of capacitors.  So no, this is not a question for RC.

Comment: And BTW, for such questions it doesn't need SE - a prior look into Wiki would have shown that red ones where the first to be mass produced in the 1960s, and it took more than a decade to stabilize a process to produce something yellowish green (I still remember that phase during the late 1970, when they started to realy look green - and gained brightness to make them usable on the same board as red ones). There is a reason that SE asks to try to search first before asking.

Comment: @Raffzahn I agree re: do your basic research first. But as far as retro **computing**, I suspect, based on his many other interesting historical questions, rwallace has a computer-specific purpose for asking but left that out as it is not directly necessary to answer the question - e.g., like writing a book with a hypothetical computer built in 19xx and needs to know what components were readily available (and at what price) to build it.

Comment: @Chenmunka White LEDs in the 1950s? **Definitely** not! In general LEDs emit one wavelength of light; light that appears white requires at least two different wave lengths. "White LEDs" today are made of a blue LED and some special material which converts a part of the blue light to yellow so blue+yellow=white. Blue LEDs however were not available before the mid-1990s.

Comment: @manassehkatz I don't feel that any computing backgroudncan make a generic EE question on topic. Especially not your book example - after all, using that would also qualify questions about 1970s cars as on topic. it the usual case of a non reverseable connection.

Comment: @MartinRosenau that is why I suspected a mixup with electroluminescent devices (or sundry kinds of micro CRT displays like magic eyes) - they can be white, and they existed in the 1950s.

Comment: @Raffzahn Having established that we disagree on the topicality question, and noting that when data are consistent with both 'OP didn't search' and 'OP searched, but missed the answer' you shouldn't assume the former - where exactly are you finding that? I just checked wiki *again* and I see lots of discussion about difficulty and timescale of manufacturing blue and white LEDs, but nothing distinguishing green from red. What am I missing?

Comment: Let’s be kind, okay?

Comment: @rwallace _"disagree on the topicality question"_ It would be helpful if you just explain why a question about a non computing specific device should be on topic, right? - Regarding Wiki, maybe reas the first history section clearly describing that red was first available in large quanitity/low price in 1968. Development was made from longwave toward short (with blue and UV last) With blue being the last and newest. And unlike you're question implies, red was allone for a long time, there was no green LED. Only green EL displays  - which others have already assumed have been mixed up here.

Comment: @rwallace I think there might be an on-topic question buried in here somewhere. *First computer with a yellow LED, with a green one, blue?* or just first product with green/yellow/red LED trio? dunno, maybe...